How to design an LPF filter for a differential input?
I want to design an anti-aliasing filter for my ADC with a cut-off of 10MHz and stopband of -15 to -20dB at 20MHz. At first i thought of using analog filter wizard or the filter design tool from TI but the circuit generated takes in single-ended inputs. Is there an online tool where i can generate LPF circuit for differential inputs? or please point me to good resources where i can learn to filter design for differential inputs.


what pp signal does your ADC need? Does your filter need minimal passband loss, or would a gain of 0.5 (-6dB) be suitable? This affects what sort of filter you design.

Analog Device APPLICATION NOTE AN-1364 addresses differential filter design ahead of ADCs

I'd filter it before the VGA and then add a simple RC filter above your cutoff on the input to the ADC to reject any thermal noise from the electronics.

@Neil_UK The Vpp is 2V. The input signal will have a high PAPR of about 12dB. So, the input signals rms power will be set to be around 9dB lower than the full-scale rms power, I think if i increase the rms power level where the VGA starts attenuating, by 6dB, it will compensate for the losses in the filter.

@glen_geek this could be what im looking for.

@user1850479 There's a BPF and saw diplexer at the front-end, the LPF is for the noise at higher frequency noise that could fold in, its pretty much what you said. But the problem i am facing is, how to filter when the input signal is differential.

If your passband is from DC to 10 MHz and, you require 15 dB to 20 dB of attenuation at 20 MHz then, you would need to design a 3rd order low-pass filter. A 3rd order low-pass filter will produce about 18 dB of attenuation at twice the cut-off frequency: -

Image taken from Wiki low-pass filter and marked up in red by me. The response above is shown relative to 1 rad/sec but it still applies if the cut-off point is 10 MHz i.e. the shape remains the same.
But, the problem is that you believe the filter needs to be differential and that brings a lot of baggage so, I would strongly consider using a differential-to-single-ended circuit at the front end using a decent op-amp and precision resistors (or maybe an instrumentation amplifier) then using a single-ended 3rd order low-pass filter based on a standard (Sallen Key) op-amp configuration like this: -

This image was taken from ReserchGate. The values are not suitable for a cut-off of 10 MHz but, that's easily solved in a simulator by checking the design and reducing the resistor and capacitor values by the same amount until 10 MHz is achieved. You will also need to choose a suitable op-amp i.e. something that has a GBWP of 100 MHz or over.
Of course you could design it using resistors, inductors and capacitors. 10 MHz is around the area where I would consider this as a decent option.
And finally, if you really do need to drive the ADC differentially then I'd consider using an inverting op-amp for this but, there are several designs out there that target more bespoke circuits and may be more suitable such as the ADA4932-1/ADA4932-2: -


Initially, i considered doing this way but i thought there could be some downside or some inefficiency in converting differential to single-ended and back to differential, i couldn't find much about this approach on the internet. In some ADC datasheet, in the application notes, there's a LC circuit for differential inputs, they used inductors of the same value on the +ve and -ve lines and shunted by a polarized capacitor. I thought of extending this to my need, but there was no mention on how to modify it.

What common mode signal noise do you have?
